# Trying to get the Amplify CI/CD release process to deploy to a separate AWS account

Tags: aws-amplify

I'm trying to get the CI/CD release process working so that when I commit to the release branch, it runs the amplify push process.

I *AM* able to `amplify push` locally without any issues (after switching branches and checking out the correct amplify environment).

This application has two environments: 'staging' and 'live'. I have two separate AWS accounts for these environments. I created and tested the project initially in staging. When testing was done, I created a new AWS account, created a new Amplify project, and connected it to the 'live' branch in my repo.

When I push commits to the 'live' branch, it starts a build, and gets through provisioning and the pre-build stages. Then I get this:

```
                                 # Starting phase: build
2022-04-06T17:57:48.997Z [INFO]: Amplify AppID found: xxxxxxxxxxxx. Amplify App name is: Project Production
2022-04-06T17:57:49.080Z [INFO]: Backend environment live found in Amplify Console app: Project Production
2022-04-06T17:57:56.229Z [WARNING]: - Fetching updates to backend environment: live from the cloud.
2022-04-06T17:58:02.363Z [WARNING]: - Building resource api/myapi
2022-04-06T17:58:13.032Z [INFO]: GraphQL schema compiled successfully.
                                 Edit your schema at /codebuild/output/src656745275/src/project-name/amplify/backend/api/myapi/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /codebuild/output/src656745275/src/project-name/amplify/backend/api/myapi/schema
2022-04-06T17:58:13.033Z [WARNING]: - Building resource api/restapi
2022-04-06T17:58:17.485Z [WARNING]: - Building resource custom/MagicLinkEmailTemplate
2022-04-06T17:58:17.486Z [WARNING]: - Building custom resources
2022-04-06T17:58:32.284Z [WARNING]: - Building resource custom/MyCustomResource
                                    - Building custom resources
2022-04-06T17:58:48.882Z [WARNING]: - Building resource custom/MyStateMachine
2022-04-06T17:58:48.883Z [WARNING]: - Building custom resources
2022-04-06T17:59:04.647Z [WARNING]: - Building resource custom/HostedZone
                                    - Building custom resources
2022-04-06T17:59:23.823Z [WARNING]: ✔ Successfully pulled backend environment live from the cloud.
2022-04-06T17:59:23.934Z [INFO]: 
2022-04-06T17:59:25.368Z [INFO]: Note: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory
2022-04-06T17:59:27.068Z [WARNING]: - Initializing your environment: live
2022-04-06T17:59:33.150Z [WARNING]: - Building resource api/myapi
2022-04-06T17:59:39.389Z [INFO]: GraphQL schema compiled successfully.
                                 Edit your schema at /codebuild/output/src656745275/src/project-name/amplify/backend/api/myapi/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /codebuild/output/src656745275/src/project-name/amplify/backend/api/myapi/schema
2022-04-06T17:59:39.390Z [WARNING]: - Building resource api/restapi
2022-04-06T17:59:43.825Z [WARNING]: - Building resource custom/MagicLinkEmailTemplate
2022-04-06T17:59:43.828Z [WARNING]: - Building custom resources
2022-04-06T17:59:50.278Z [WARNING]: - Building resource custom/MyCustomResource
                                    - Building custom resources
2022-04-06T17:59:58.898Z [WARNING]: - Building resource custom/MyStateMachine
                                    - Building custom resources
2022-04-06T18:00:06.435Z [WARNING]: - Building resource custom/HostedZone
                                    - Building custom resources
2022-04-06T18:00:16.067Z [WARNING]: ✔ Initialized provider successfully.
2022-04-06T18:00:17.268Z [INFO]: 
2022-04-06T18:00:17.274Z [INFO]: Suggested configuration for new layer versions:
2022-04-06T18:00:17.282Z [INFO]: myappLayerGraphQL
                                 - Access permissions: Maintain existing permissions
                                 - Description: Updated layer version  2022-04-06T18:00:17.273Z
                                 myappLayerAxios
                                 - Access permissions: Maintain existing permissions
                                 - Description: Updated layer version  2022-04-06T18:00:17.273Z
                                 myappLayerLodash
                                 - Access permissions: Maintain existing permissions
                                 - Description: Updated layer version  2022-04-06T18:00:17.273Z
                                 myappLayerStripe
                                 - Access permissions: Maintain existing permissions
                                 - Description: Updated layer version  2022-04-06T18:00:17.273Z
2022-04-06T18:00:17.282Z [INFO]: 
2022-04-06T18:00:31.140Z [WARNING]: ✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud
2022-04-06T18:00:31.162Z [WARNING]: ✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
2022-04-06T18:00:31.170Z [INFO]: Error: Packaging lambda function failed with the error
                                 Command failed with exit code 1: npm install --production
                                 npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
                                 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src656745275/src/project-name/amplify/backend/function/myappLayerGraphQL/lib/nodejs/node_modules/.staging/graphql-03f7efb5/language/directiveLocation.mjs'
                                 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src656745275/src/project-name/amplify/backend/function/myappLayerGraphQL/lib/nodejs/node_modules/.staging/graphql-03f7efb5/type/directives.mjs'
                                 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src656745275/src/project-name/amplify/backend/function/myappLayerGraphQL/lib/nodejs/node_modules/.staging/graphql-03f7efb5/execution/execute.mjs'
......
```

Those errors go on for about 400 more lines...

I don't know what that .staging directory is or where it came from -- it's not in my actual layer, I don't see references to 'staging' in any files in that entire layer directory.

Any help, please?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something changed in Amplify and I started getting a different error message which led me to the solution.

It turns out that I hadn't properly authorized the build process to install the private NPM package I had up on GitHub Package Manager. I dropped the `.npmrc` file that I had in my local user directory into the directory that contained the `package.json` for the function that was failing and it started working.

Simple solution made more difficult by bad error logging...